# Athena count duplicate rows over two tables

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Is it possible to compare the unique values of two columns in athena outputting the count of the duplicate values over the two columns?

I have two tables with the following data in the ID column

Table A:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Table B:

```
AAA
BBB
DDD
```

The output for this data should be 2 as two unique values in table A are in table B.
How would I go about comparing different tables like this?

Answer (score 2):

Using join and counting distinct elements should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct Table1.Id)
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `b` is unique, you can try:

```
select count(*)
from b
where exists (select 1 from a where a.col = b.col);
```